# Insert <p> element inside an input on button click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem where I need to change the HTML inside of a `<button></button>`. Here are the relevant lines of HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="subject" />
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btv"><p>Text 1</p></button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btc"><p>Text 2</p></button>
```

And this is the jQuery:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var text = $('.btn p').html();
    $('#subject').val(text);
});
```

All I have managed to do is make the first text show no matter which button I press. I really need a bit of help.

Comment: Sorry, but why you have an paragraph on your Button?

Comment: because you select all the elements, not the one that was clicked....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***First of all `paragraph` inside `button` in not valid `HTML`.***

But in this case also you can make your code working through the use of `$(this)` along with `.children()` like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn').click(function(){
    $('#subject').val($(this).children('p').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="subject" />
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btv"><p>Text 1</p></button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btc"><p>Text 2</p></button>
```

Note:-

Make sure that jQuery library added before your script code.

If you are adding your script code on top of page then it should be wrapped inside `$(document).ready(function(){..});`, but if you are adding script code at the bottom of the page then it's not necessary (in both case jQuery library need to be added before code)

***A valid HTML example is like below:-***

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $('#subject').val($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="subject" />
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btv">Text 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btc">Text 2</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
var text = $(this).html();
$('#subject').val(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="subject" />
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btv">Text 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btc">Text 2</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#subject').val( $(this).text() )
```

Comment: Code-only answers are often unhelpful in pointing to why your solution is helpful. Please include an explanation for why your code solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use text and context

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('#subject').val($(this).text());
});
```